# How to associate an Office 365 Trial account with my own domain?

Tags: dns, ms-office, office365

How can I associate the office 365 trial account with my own domain?

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom domain name to Office 365, use the Add domain wizard as follows.

- On the Admin page, in the left pane, under Management, click Domains, and then click Add a domain.
- On the Add a domain page, under Specify domain, type the domain name that you want to add, and then click Next.
- Follow the steps in the wizard to verify with Office 365 that the domain name you have added belongs to you. For step-by-step directions, see Verify a domain at any domain name registrar.

Up to date help: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/ff637620.aspx

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it's just a link and may become broken in the future.  It would be preferable to [include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I did what you request, but I actually think it's a bad idea. Office 365 is an evolving product, and this link will include up to date information, unlink my answer.